# Is B 737 Max able to comply with certification if MCAS is off or removed?

Tags: faa-regulations, boeing-737

Boeing 737 Max updated MCAS will probably be cutted off in case of AoA disagree. Without MCAS, the plane is no longer similar to 737 NG (stick force per g requirement). Does that mean a new certification ?

Comment: Thanks Bianfable. The question is not about MCAS role (answered by this previous question), but about new certification or not.

Comment: So,  that means MCAS must be present and fail-safe ?

Comment: I think the linked question answers this. Without MACS the airplane would be terribly difficult to fly by human pilots under certain conditions, but the FAA have formalized rules against difficult to fly airplanes.